# Create a ListView of CheckedTextView elements where the first element is editable

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appwidget

I have a configuration activity for an AppWidget. I want to let the user choose an existing string for the widget, or create one of their own by selecting the first option and editing the text within the list.

How do I change the element type of just the first list item to a different type of view that will allow users to insert custom text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListAdapter` interface has two methods `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.  So in your case, they might be implemented like this:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // first position has view type == 0; all others have view type == 1
    return position == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

What this does is make sure that the correct views are recycled for the correct positions.  Once you have these methods, then you can do:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (position == 0) {
        // create a custom edit view and return it
    } else {
        // create a selection view and return it
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So there is no way to do it without creating my own Adapter?

Comment: Well, you said `ListView`.  You don't have to have an adapter if you have, say, a `LinearLayout` and create & add each item view to it...

Comment: I was just hoping there would be a way to do this sort of thing already in the Adapter class. Android seems to really like making you extend existing classes.